# Converting python regex code to kotlin or java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'[\1]', '(201) 555-0123')
'([201]) [555]-[0123]'
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'[\1]', '312 345 6789')
'[312] [345] [6789]'
```

Hello, how can i convert this python regex code to kotlin or java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for explicitly wrap entire regex in parenthesis to place entire match in group 1, since group 0 already does it for us.

In Java your regex can look like

```java
String yourString = "(201) 555-0123";
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("\\d+", "[$0]");
System.out.println(yourString);  //Output: ([201]) [555]-[0123]

yourString = "312 345 6789";
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("\\d+", "[$0]");
System.out.println(yourString);  //Output: [312] [345] [6789]
```

`$x` in replacement allows us to reuse part from group `x`, so `$0` uses match from group 0, meaning entire current regex match.